# Integer overflow using lazy sequences in Clojure

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation, integer-overflow

I'm just learning to use lazy sequences in Clojure, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in the following code:

```
(defn sum [seqn]
  (reduce + seqn))

(defn fib
  ([] (concat [0 1] (fib 0 1)))
  ([a b] (lazy-seq (cons (+ a b) (fib b (+ a b))))))

(defn up-to [n seqn]
  (filter (fn [x] (< x n)) seqn))

(sum (up-to 100 (fib))) => ArithmeticException integer overflow  clojure.lang.Numbers.throwIntOverflow (Numbers.java:1388)
```

The numbers being summed shouldn't be larger than `100`, so what is causing the integer overflow?

Comment: I encountered this issue, trying to solve the same problem: Project Euler, problem number 2!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filtering an infinite seq produces an infinite seq and reducing over this causes filter to keep looking for another matching item even after the predicate stops returning true.

Replace `filter` with `take-while`. The infinite sequence generated by `(fib)` will cause `filter` to run forever, but before that it will break due to the `ArithmeticException` you're experiencing. `take-while` will stop further evaluation of the list after the `(fn [x] (< x n))` predicate evaluates to false.

```
(defn up-to [n seqn]
  (take-while (fn [x] (< x n)) seqn))

(sum (up-to 100 (fib))) ;; => 232
```

Comment: How does filter evaluate the whole list? I thought it was supposed to produce a lazy seq?

Comment: Never mind, I see... it's not the filter itself. Filtering an infinite seq produces an infinite seq, and reducing over this causes filter to keep looking for another matching item even after the predicate stops returning true.

Comment: Got it, seems like Alex's reasoning is more accurate than the answers. Please update the answer so that I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Chetan, done. Does it cut it now? @Alex, thanks for your comments.

Comment: A good way to bring home the difference between take-while and filter.

Answer (score 5):

starting with clojure 1.3.0 numbers don't auto-promote to bigInt/bigDecimal.

to fix this use `+'` instead

your 100th fibinachi number is too large for an integer

```
user> (nth (fib) 100)
354224848179261915075N
```

Comment: I don't think he's summing the first 100 Fibonacci numbers, but the Fibonacci numbers which are less than 100.

Comment: yes, this is a separate answer for a different problem from the one addressed in Jan's answer.